# Postgres equivalent for TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ

Tags: postgresql

What would be the Postgres equivalent for `TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ` function in oracle.

For the below query:

```
SELECT TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ('1998-01-01') FROM DUAL;
```

The result is "01-JAN-98 12.00.00.000000000 AM GMT" in oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what the Oracle function does, but I think this should be equivalent:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('1998-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'GMT'
```

Answer (score 0):

Append `'T00:00 UTC'` and cast to `timestamptz`.

```sql
select ('1998-01-01'||'T00:00 UTC')::timestamptz;
```

Check:

```sql
select to_char(
 ('1998-01-01'||'T00:00 UTC')::timestamptz, 
 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.us OF'
);
```

Result "1998-01-01 02:00:00.000000 +02".
This is exactly the same as  "01-JAN-98 12.00.00.000000000 AM GMT".

It might make sense to define a compatibility function.

```sql
create function to_utc_timestamp_tz(ts text) returns timestamptz immutable as
$$
 select (ts || 'T00:00 UTC')::timestamptz;
$$ language sql;
```